# Sending POST request with NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, web-services

I am sending a post Request with the some  parameter in the request body.

Here is the iOS code:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:purchaseURL];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithString:@"userid=1&couponid=1&Ccnum=7b6cd9a44365752cf39c1edf97890b72&Cctype=Visa&Cvv=434&Billingfirstname=Ankit&Billinglastname=Ankit&Street=some&getCity=mycity&State=mystate&getZip=54355&Ccexpmonth=5&Ccexpyear=2012&Phone=43423342"];
NSMutableData *postData=[NSMutableData data];
[postData appendData:[requestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSLog(@"content length %d",[postData length]);
[request setValue:@"text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSLog(@"purchage url string %@",postData);

connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];


  NSAssert(self.connection != nil, @"Failure to create URL connection.");
```

This is the php file that will handle the post request. It handles the input and the response is in JSON format.

```
 public function restpurchaseAction(Request $request)
 {

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $couponid = $POST['couponid'];



    //Check that email was verified
//Get the user object to compare id to the listed deals id
if(!$user->getEmailVerified())
{
    return "Error:  Must verify email before making a purchase.";
}


// Initialize error varible
$error = "";


//get the currently logged in user
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('FrontendUserBundle:User');
        $user = $repository->findOneByUsername($userid);
//get the coupon that is being purchased
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('FrontendUserBundle:Coupon');
    $coupon = $repository->findOneById($couponid);        

//get the number of times the user has purchased and compare to maxper
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
->getRepository('FrontendUserBundle:Purchase');     
//if they have already purchased max, redirect to error page
$purchases = $repository->findByCouponAndUser($coupon->getId(), $user->getId());
if(count($purchases) >= $coupon->getMaxper() && $coupon->getMaxper() != 0){
    "Error: Coupon purchased maximum number of times.";
}

//get the users profile
$profile = $user->getProfile();

//get the users address
$address = $profile->getAddress();

//initialize the new purchase
$purchase = new Purchase();

//generate the coupon verification code
$currentdate = new \DateTime();
$currentdate->setTimestamp(time());
$interval = new \DateInterval('P'.$coupon->getExpirationdate().'D');
$currentdate->add($interval);
$validationnumber1 = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
$validationnumber2 = mt_rand(1000000, 9999999);
$validationnumber = $validationnumber1 . $validationnumber2;

//set up all the values for the purchase object
$purchase->setValidationnumber($validationnumber);
$purchase->setUser($user);
$purchase->setCoupon($coupon);
$purchase->setValid(true);
$purchase->setValidationattempts(1);
$purchase->setExpirationDate($currentdate);
$card = $purchase->getCard();
$card->setCcnum($_POST['Ccnum']);
$card->setCctype($_POST['Cctype']);
$card->setCvv($_POST['Cvv']);
$card->setUserid($user->getId());

//If the form has already been submitted then check if it is a valid CC.  
//If so, then finish the purchase,else return to the start.
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST'){
    //Get post variables for credit card.

        //Live Mode Credentials
        define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "**********");
        define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "***************");
        //Test Mode Credentials
        //define("AUTHORIZENET_API_LOGIN_ID", "*************");
        //define("AUTHORIZENET_TRANSACTION_KEY", "*****************");
        define("AUTHORIZENET_SANDBOX", false);
        $response="declined";

        //Make sure maxlimit hasn't been reached before processing.
        if($coupon->getMaxLimit() == 0 || $coupon->getNumPurchased()<=$coupon-                                                                                                                                     >getMaxLimit())
        {

        $sale = new AuthorizeNetAIM;

        /*Input coupon information. */
        $item_id = $coupon->getID();
        $item_name = substr($coupon->getCouponname(), 0, 31);
        $item_description = substr($coupon->getDescription(), 0,255);
        $item_quantity = 1;
        $item_unit_price = $coupon->getPrice();
        $item_taxable = FALSE;
        $billingaddress = $purchase->getBillingaddress();
        $card = $purchase->getCard();

        /*Input customer information. */
        $sale->setField('first_name', $_POST['Billingfirstname']);
        $sale->setField('last_name', $_POST['Billinglastname']);
        $sale->setField('email', $user->getEmail);
        $sale->setField('address', $_POST['Street']);
        $sale->setField('city', $_POST['getCity']);
        $sale->setField('state', $_POST['State']);
        $sale->setField('zip', $_POST['getZip']);
        $sale->setField('phone', $_POST['Phone']);


        /*Add information to the sale */
        $sale->addLineItem($item_id, $item_name, $item_description, $item_quantity, $item_unit_price, $item_taxable);
        $sale->amount = $coupon->getPrice();
        $sale->card_num = $_POST['Ccnum'];
        $sale->exp_date = $_POST['Ccexpmonth'] . '/' . $_POST['Ccexpyear'];
        $sale->setField('card_code', $_POST['Cvv']);

        $response = $sale->authorizeAndCapture();
        if ($response->approved) {
            //Prepersist, make sure to remove CVV, and extra CC digits, only store last 4
            $card->setCvv("");
            $lastfour = substr($card->getCcnum(), -4);
            $card->setCcnum($lastfour);
            $transaction_id = $response->transaction_id;
            $purchase->setId = $transaction_id;
            $coupon->incrementNumPurchased();
            $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($purchase);
            $em->persist($coupon);
            $em->flush();
            return "Coupon Purchase Successful!";

    }else{

        $error = $response->error_message;
     }
    }
    else{

        $error = "Maximum number of coupons already purchased!";

    }

 }

return $error;


}
```

I am unable to find the error or any issue in the code. I have also tried ASIHttpRequest/ASIFormDataRequest but was unable to get that to work. Is there a problem in the way i am calling the web service?

Comment: Welcome to SO - your question, as it currently stands is not easy to answer as you are posting a wall of PHP-code containing a lot of unrelated stuff. You also do not tell us what the results from your posted data are. Have you tried to simply log the entire post on the server side to see what is received? Have you tried using a proxy (e.g. Charles) to monitor the communication between device and server?

Comment: I am not sure but try replacing NSUTF8StringEncoding with NSASCIIStringEncoding...

Comment: **WAIT!** You post a Credit Card Number directly with its CCV and expiry date in 1 single POST request? It probably did not comply with PCI DSS Standard.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to debug this, is to actually check what kind of error or response you are getting when starting the connection. To do this, I suggest you let your class implement the following delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Did fail with error %@" , [error localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse;
    httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
    NSLog(@"Status code was %d", statusCode);
}
```

This will hopefully give you a better idea of what happens. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok, so 404 is a HTTP status code returned from the server side, so the HTTP-post is successfully sent to the server. 

On the server side, try logging the request parameters, and find out why it returns 404 to the client.

Comment: @ThomasJohanEggum 404 = not found = the URL used by the client is incorrect, maybe a typo.

Comment: sir, that means my way of calling web service is correct, so it might be problem with web service.....? i have no work experience with php it has been written by some body else.

Comment: 404 is a status code that the server application sends in a HTTP-response package. It is up to the developer of the server side code to send the correct HTTP-response codes in different cases. 
Please read http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for HTTP-response code specifications.
My quess is that the PHP-script does not find the user you are requesting, and there fore sending a 404.

Do you know if the server side works? If not, try using CURL or some other client application to generate a POST-request to test if it works the way you want.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below , it might help you ...

```
NSString *purchaseURL=@"your url string inside";

NSString *postString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=1&couponid=1&Ccnum=7b6cd9a44365752cf39c1edf97890b72&Cctype=Visa&Cvv=434&Billingfirstname=Ankit&Billinglastname=Ankit&Street=some&getCity=mycity&State=mystate&getZip=54355&Ccexpmonth=5&Ccexpyear=2012&Phone=43423342"];

NSData *postData=[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:purchaseURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

NSError *err=nil;

NSData *responseData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];
NSString *responseString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"response String is  %@",responseString);
```

If still will give some error try changing post string as given below

```
    NSMutableDictionary *postDix=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[postDix setValue:@"1" forKey:@"userid"];
[postDix setValue:@"7b6cd9a44365752cf39c1edf97890b72" forKey:@"Ccnum"];
[postDix setValue:@"Visa" forKey:@"Cctype"];
[postDix setValue:@"434" forKey:@"Cvv"];
[postDix setValue:@"Ankit" forKey:@"Billingfirstname"];
[postDix setValue:@"Ankit" forKey:@"Billinglastname"];
[postDix setValue:@"some" forKey:@"Street"];
[postDix setValue:@"mycity" forKey:@"getCity"];
[postDix setValue:@"mystate" forKey:@"State"];
[postDix setValue:@"54355" forKey:@"getZip"];
[postDix setValue:@"5" forKey:@"Ccexpmonth"];
[postDix setValue:@"2012" forKey:@"Ccexpyear"];
[postDix setValue:@"43423342" forKey:@"Phone"];

NSString *postString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", postDix];
```

OR changing post data as :-

```
NSMutableDictionary *postDix=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[postDix setValue:@"1" forKey:@"userid"];
[postDix setValue:@"7b6cd9a44365752cf39c1edf97890b72" forKey:@"Ccnum"];
[postDix setValue:@"Visa" forKey:@"Cctype"];
[postDix setValue:@"434" forKey:@"Cvv"];
[postDix setValue:@"Ankit" forKey:@"Billingfirstname"];
[postDix setValue:@"Ankit" forKey:@"Billinglastname"];
[postDix setValue:@"some" forKey:@"Street"];
[postDix setValue:@"mycity" forKey:@"getCity"];
[postDix setValue:@"mystate" forKey:@"State"];
[postDix setValue:@"54355" forKey:@"getZip"];
[postDix setValue:@"5" forKey:@"Ccexpmonth"];
[postDix setValue:@"2012" forKey:@"Ccexpyear"];
[postDix setValue:@"43423342" forKey:@"Phone"];

NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:postData];
[archiver encodeObject:postDix forKey:@"json"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
```